# jquery - How to detect input type and adjust it

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML...

```
<input type="button".... class="m-button">
```

I want detect if .m-button has a type "button".  If it does, then change the type to "submit"

Is this possible?

Comment: When do you want to detect this? When the page loads? When the button it pressed? There's a way, but we need the when.

Comment: `$('.m-button[type="button"]').prop('type','submit')`

Comment: when the page is done loading - on window load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var buttons = $('.m-button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    if(buttons.eq(i).prop('type') == 'button'){
        buttons.eq(i).prop('type', 'submit');
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh found the problem, which connects to your solution.  prop is preferred over attr in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var $button = $('.m-button');
if($button.attr('type') == 'button')
    $button.attr('type') = 'submit';
```

if you have multiple `.m-button`s on the page, you could do it in an each:

```
$('.m-button').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('type') == 'button')
        $(this).attr('type') = 'submit';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".m-button[type='button']").attr("type", "submit");
```

Comment: You want to change the `<input type="button"...>` to `<input type="input"...>`?? Edit: That's better, but has been said in the comments too. :)

Comment: @TimLewis, it's typo :)

Comment: hmmm...when i put this into the console in Chrome, it tells me "type property cannot be changed"

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('.m-button').attr("type")=="button" )
{
    $('.m-button').attr("type","submit");
}
```

Comment: Does it work if multiple tags have the `m-button` class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's the shorter selection & works perfectly, give a try. See [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/044pv3ad/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('input:button.m-button').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('type','submit');
    });
});
```